# Как создать фоновый процесс в apache cordova

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, apache, cordova

Как в Apache cordova (Которая встроена в Visual Studio) сделать фоновый процесс вызывающийся раз в 5 минут либо работающий вечно(тогда на js напишу чтоб раз в 5 минут вызывалась функция), который бы вызывал js код. js код отправлял бы запрос серверу и в случае необходимости делал уведомление на телефоне?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл плагин для Apache Cordova: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: да, тут без плагина никак.